# `sentry/sdk 2.x` - how to register it's error / exception handling

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, sentry

While we are using multiple instances of sentry at once I dropped the default initialization of the Sentry client and managed to create the Sentry client manually.

```php
$client = ClientBuilder::create(
    [
        'dsn'         => $this->config->getDsn(),
        'environment' => $this->config->getEnvironment(),
        'release'     => $this->config->getRelease(),
        'error_types' => $this->config->getErrorReporting()
    ]
)->getClient();
```

I'm now able to capture exceptions / errors or messages manually.

```php
$client->captureException( ... );
```

But what I don't get is how to register Sentry's exception / error handlers manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We handle global unhandled exceptions via integrations.
Integrations work a bit different since they are essentially singletons and need to be able to keep a global state since we for example do not want to hook multiple times in the the global handlers.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to use `Hub` instead of the `Client` directly.

```php
$client1 = Sentry\ClientBuilder::create([
  'dsn' => 'DSN'
])->getClient();

$hub1 = new Sentry\State\Hub($client1);
// Making a Hub current, tells the global integrations to send stuff to the client registered in this Hub
Sentry\SentrySdk::setCurrentHub($hub1);

// This will be caught by and send by $client1
throw new Exception('DEMO TEST3');

$client2 = Sentry\ClientBuilder::create([
  'dsn' => 'DSN'
])->getClient();

$hub2 = new Sentry\State\Hub($client2);
// Setting a new current hub here
Sentry\SentrySdk::setCurrentHub($hub2);

// This will be caught by and send by $client2
throw new Exception('DEMO TEST4');
```

So only one hub can be the current hub at a time, so one of your clients must be the one handling global exceptions.
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes. I also discovered this and was about to write a `HubCollection` implementing the `HubInterface`. This would've been a good sulotion to trigger more than one client. But then a colleague remembered me there is always only one errorhandler registered at a time.